# Why prestashop doesn't return product attachment's ids?

Tags: php, prestashop, attachment, prestashop-1.6

I added a test.pdf attchment to a product:

[image]

The attachment is properly saved on db:

[image]

In CategoryController I'm looking for attachments like this:

```
$prod->getAttachments();
```

But if I try to log the results, I get something like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(9) {
    ["id_product"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["id_attachment"]=>
    NULL
    ["file"]=>
    string(40) "725abb2b97837af5f29e589c56becb09b91e0c1a"
    ["file_name"]=>
    string(8) "test.pdf"
    ["file_size"]=>
    string(4) "9453"
    ["mime"]=>
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["id_lang"]=>
    NULL
    ["name"]=>
    NULL
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

You can see that the file_name is correct but the id_attachment field is not populated, so I cannot build any link via Link->getPageLink as usual.

Why it doesn't return the id? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer by myself: `$prod->getAttachments();` needs id_lang to be passed.